# intersection of plane an elliptical cone - points in 3D space are correct in some cases but not others

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have successfully used Peter Paul Klein's algorithm (found here: 
   [On The Ellipsoid and Plane Intersection Equation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234034616_On_the_Ellipsoid_and_Plane_Intersection_Equation)) to compute the general 3D curve of intersection of any ellipsoid $(\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2+(\frac{z}{c})^2 = 1$ and any plane $ix+jy+kz+d=0$ where $(i,j,k)$ is the plane normal.

I have also modified his math to do the same for the general intersection of an elliptical cone $(\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2 = (\frac{z}{c})^2 $ and plane for the case when conic coefficients $B^2-4AC < 0$, i.e. when the curve is an **ellipse**.

I'm now working on the case when $B^2-4AC = 0$, i.e when the curve is a **parabola**.  I've run into problems so I've applied the following basic tests to verify I can generate correct points in 3D space.

**Step 1.** Solve the conic for "easy" planes (axis-aligned) and cones, compute $z=f(x,y)$ for each point and verify that it is on the plane and the cone.
   **This is easy enough and works.**
   For example, the plane $$0x + -y + z -11.3137084989848 = 0$$ and the cone $$z^2 = \left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^2 + (y)^2$$ intersect along the curve $y = 0.00276213586400995x^2 + -5.65685424949239$.
This is done by solving the plane for $z$, squaring it and setting the two $z^2$ equations equal.
You can verify that the conic is a parabola since $B=C=0$ and thus $B^2-4AC = 0$.
Here's an example test point: $x = 576.0$, $y=f(x)=910.753534168266$. And, using the equation of the plane, $z=f(x,y) = 922.067242667251$.
This point lies on the boundary of the cone $z^2 = (\frac{x}{4})^2 + y^2$.

**Step 2.** I then do the same for a plane that is not axis-aligned but a circular cone.
**This is also easy and works**.
For example, the plane $$x + y + √2z -4 = 0$$ and the cone $$z^2 = x^2 + y^2$$ intersect along the curve $0.5x^2 + 0.5y^2 - xy + 4x + 4y - 8 = 0$ where you can verify that $B^2-4AC = 1-4(0.5)(0.5) = 0$ meaning the conic is a parabola.
When rewritten as $5y^2+ (-10x+40)y+(5x^2+40x-80) = 0$, I can use the quadratic equation to solve for $y$ where $a=5, b=(-10x+40)$ and $c=(5x^2+40x-80)$.
Here's an example test point: $x = -310.0, y=-243.345913069377$ (one root of the quadratic equation). And using the equation of the plane, $z=f(x,y) = 394.103074597965$.  This point lies precisely on the boundary of the cone $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$.

**My question at long last!**
When I intersect an elliptical cone with a non-axis-aligned plane, the solution I derive produces points ***not*** on the cone.
Consider the plane $$x + y + \sqrt{5}z -5 = 0$$ and the cone $$z^2=x^2 + (y/2)^2.$$
I'll show a bit of the algebra so it's easier to follow.
  $$(-\sqrt{5}z)^2 = (x + y - 5)^2$$
  $$z^2 = \frac{(x + y - 5)^2}{5}$$
  $$z^2 = \frac{[x^2 + 2xy + y^2 + -10x + -10y + 25]}{5}$$
  $$z^2 = 0.2x^2 + xy + 0.2y^2 + -2x + -2y + 5$$
Once again, you can verify this is a parabola via $B^2-4AC = 0$.
Equate the two to get: $x^2 + 0.25y^2 = 0.2x^2 + xy + 0.2y^2 + -2x + -2y + 5$
Simplify to get: $0.8x^2 + 0.05y^2 - xy + 2x + 2y - 5 = 0$
Multiply everything by 100 and write in $(ay^2 + by + c = 0)$ form to get: $$5y^2+ (-100x+200)y+(80x^2+200x-500) = 0$$
  Solve this quadratic equation for $y$ with $a = 5, b = -100x+200$ and $c = 80x^2+200x-500$ using appropriate $x$ values.  As before solve $z=f(x,y)$ using the equation of the plane.
Here's the problem: $\forall x \neq 0$, this produces points not on the cone at all.
E.g. $x=1.2, y=f(x)=-17.6415766345552$ (one of two roots), and $z=f(x,y) = 9.5889645799273$.
Plugging $(x,y,z)$ into the equation of the cone produces $1.2^2 + (\frac{-17.6415766345552}{2})^2 - 9.5889645799273^2 = -12.7019351768797 \neq 0$.

I expect there is something basic that I'm doing wrong or not understanding.  Would you show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let’s get a big error that you’re making out of the way first. In your question proper, you take the equation of the cutting plane, solve for $z$, square and then examine the discriminant of the resulting expression in $x$ and $y$. This tells you nothing about the nature of the intersection between this plane and the quadric surface: this discriminant will always vanish. Algebraically, $B^2-4AC=0$ tells you that the second-degree terms in the general conic equation are the square of a linear term (which is indeed the hallmark of a parabola, possibly degenerate), but that’s how we obtained those second-degree terms in the first place. You need to examine the discriminant of the conic equation obtained by substituting for $z$ in the equation of the quadric.

Moving on, you’ve made a simple algebraic error when squaring the plane equation. In the next-to-last equation, you have the term $2xy$ in the numerator, but somehow that turned into $xy$ when you divided by $5$. That’s going to throw all of the rest of your calculations off.

Using the correct expression for $z^2$, equating the two produces the equation $$\frac45x^2-\frac25xy+\frac1{20}y^2+2x+2y-5=0.$$ One could clear the denominators, but I don’t see any compelling reason to do so yet. Solving this for $y$ we get $$y=2\left(2x-10\pm\sqrt{5-2x}\right).$$ Using your value of $x=1.2$, we get $y\approx-31.325$ and $y\approx0.925$, and plugging this into the equation of the plane yields $z\approx 15.708$ and $z\approx1.286$, respectively. These values satisfy the equation of the cone, as expected.

I haven’t read the linked paper, but presumably once you have this projected curve, you then use standard methods and formulas to analyze the conic, then project back onto the cutting plane. If the cutting plane is parallel to the $z$-axis, you need to project onto one of the other coordinates instead since the projection onto the $x$-$y$ plane will be a line, line segment or point, so that’s a special case to deal with. Orthogonal projection of one plane onto another that’s not orthogonal to it is an affine transformation, which doesn’t change the nature of a conic, so this method certainly works, but I think that it would be just as easy (outside of contrived examples and exercises in which the numbers are “nice”) to obtain a planar conic equation that represents the intersection curve exactly instead of working with some affine image of it.

Choose a pair of linearly-independent vector $\mathbf U$ and $\mathbf V$ parallel to the cutting plane and a point $P_0$ on it. (I’ll use upper-case for points and vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ and lower-case for $\mathbb R^2$.) This point and vectors form a coordinate system for the plane. That is, every point $\mathbf P$ on the plane can be written as $P=u\mathbf U+v\mathbf V+\mathbf P_0$ for unique scalars $u$ and $v$. These scalars are the coordinates of the point in the plane’s coordinate system. We can write the preceding expression in matrix form as $$\mathbf P = \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf U&\mathbf V&\mathbf P_0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\1\end{bmatrix} = M\mathbf p.$$ Here we’ve passed to homogeneous coordinates in order to represent this affine transformation as a matrix multiplication.

In a similar fashion, we can write the general quadric equation in homogeneous matrix form as $\mathbf P^TQ\mathbf P=0$, where $Q$ is a symmetric $4\times 4$ matrix. However, since $\mathbf P=M\mathbf p$, we have $\mathbf P^TQ\mathbf P = (M\mathbf p)^TQ(M\mathbf p) = \mathbf p^T(M^TQM)\mathbf p=0$. So, in the coordinate system that we’ve established for the plane, the equation of the intersection curve has the equation $\mathbf p^T(M^TQM)\mathbf p=0$. This has the form of a general conic equation, so the intersection of a plane with *any* quadric surface is a conic (perhaps degenerate).

If we pick $\mathbf U$ and $\mathbf V$ to be orthonormal, then, we can analyze the intersection curve directly. You still have to convert points and vectors back into the original $3$-D coordinate system, but that’s just a matter of multiplying by $M$. Finding such an orthonormal basis is fairly simple: For any nonzero vector $(a,b,c)$, at least two of $(0,-c,b)$, $(c,0,-a)$ and $(-b,a,0)$ are also nozero. All are orthogonal to $(a,b,c)$. So, take a normal vector $\mathbf N$, to the plane, which you can extract from its equation, and choose a convenient-looking one of the above, normalized, for $\mathbf U$. Set $\mathbf V$ to $\mathbf N\times\mathbf U$, also normalized. A suitable origin $\mathbf P_0$ can be found by setting two of the three variables to zero in the plane equation.

Taking your last example, we have a choice of $(0,-\sqrt5,1)$, $(\sqrt5,0,-1)$ and $(-1,1,0)$ for $\mathbf U$. Let’s take the last one. $(1,1,\sqrt5)\times(-1,1,0)=(-\sqrt5,-\sqrt5,2)$, and we can take $(5,0,0)$ for the origin, producing $$M = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\sqrt{\frac5{14}}&5\\\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\sqrt{\frac5{14}}&0\\0&\sqrt{\frac27}&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ For the cone, $Q=\operatorname{diag}\left(1,\frac14,-1,0\right)$ and so we have $$C = M^TQM = \begin{bmatrix}\frac58&\frac38\sqrt{\frac57}&-\frac5{\sqrt2}\\\frac38\sqrt{\frac57}&\frac9{56}&-5\sqrt{\frac5{14}}\\-\frac5{\sqrt2}&-5\sqrt{\frac5{14}}&25\end{bmatrix}.$$ The upper-left minor vanishes and $\det C\ne0$, so this is a parabola that we can then proceed to analyze using standard methods and formulas. For instance, one of its principal axes makes an angle $\theta$ with the $u$-axis, where $\tan{2\theta} = \frac3{13}\sqrt{35}$, for $\theta\approx26.89°$.

Comment: Before I forget, thank you.  I cannot say how much I appreciate you reading through the very long question and helping me understanding I'm not crazy and am instead just full of basic algebra errors and lack of deep understanding. Apologies for not making it clear that the B^2-4AC comment meant the conic equation. The papers I reference do something similar - they derive the 'center' of the ellipse or the hyperbola of intersection and then generate the curve parametrically using U and V.